# Nginx pictures loading from bad url - need to put */path/* in url

Tags: image, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am currently setting up reverse proxy for one of our customers, and there is this problem where everything is loading correctly but only few pictures (icons) aren't loaded because there is a bad path for some reason.

Easily said I need https://example.com/picture.png to take that picture from https://example.com **/prod/** picture.png

For some reason this path is not edited. But when I check the file url in F12 where it got 404 and add that /prod/ in its path, I am forwarded to the site with the picture displayed so the permissions should be ok.

Every other thing is forwarded correctly except these pictures. Is there a way to tell these pictures to take the file from the new path instead of the old one. Some kind of rewrite or redirect.

I currently have only this basic setup which works for everything else.

```
location /prod/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:8080/;
}
```

I have tried few rewrite rules, but none of them seemed to work. I and somewhat new to nginx so I am not sure about the syntaxes. Also is there a need to enable something additional for rewriting?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: no need to go for a answer here. this is very well documented everywhere. Try using a location block with the images extensions only, then use a `try_files` that corresponds to what you need. `try_files $uri /prod$uri something_else /?q=404;` or better... pass everything to your upstream, which seems to be what you are doing anyways. This also doesn't have much to do with reverse-proxy or proxy category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /prod {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:8080/;
}
```

You need to have it **without** slash at the end, otherwise, Nginx tries to match it exactly to "/prod/".